# How to visualise a data in dashboard for huge number of variables?

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-comparisons, large-data

Consider I want to visualise the sales figure of 10 products in a dashboard (I will use HTML5 and JS). My data contains product name, total QoQ (Quarter on Quarter) of sales, QoQ of sales in US, QoQ of sales in GB and QoQ of sales in Eur. I want to visualise the data using plots/graphs/charts.

I tried with spyder/radar chart but it is not appealing.

Moreover, I have one more set of data for 70 products and for consistency, I have to use the same visualisation as former and if I use spyder/radar chart, it will look horrible.

Can any one suggest a good way to visualise a large data in a easy way?

I don't want to represent them as a numbers in table since, it will look cumbersome. And any visual queue is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way to visualise a lot of indicators is [sparklines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline). Also refer to [Edward Tufte's website](https://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001OR) for ideas on how to use them.